# ulkJson usage in Delphi 6

Tags: json, delphi

lets says i have a code like this,

```
  json:= TlkJSON.ParseText(Memo1.Text);
  if Assigned(json) then
  begin
    json:= json.Field['journals'];
    if Assigned(json) then
    begin
      json:= json.Field['journal_details'];
      if Assigned(json) then
      begin
        Memo2.Lines.Add(VarToStr(json.Child[0].Value));
      end;
    end;

  end;
```

it's used for tracing my json object had field "journals" and "journal_details" in it.

I want to make it more dynamic so it can detect if the value in json object was array/list/custom list and it contain all the detail error message i want to re - translate again so the user can understand the message.

Any clue will be appreciated.

as @MyICQ suggestion, this is snippet of data that i want to re - translate look like.

```
[{"code":"H003","validations":["phone_invalid_format"]},{"code":"H004","validations":["phone_invalid_format"]},{"code":"H005","validations":["phone_invalid_format"]},{"code":"H006","validations":["phone_invalid_format"]},{"code":"H010","validations":["phone_invalid_format"]}]
```

with note, the string was not always with the same structure.

this is the output, i wish to have at least

```
Error List Data :
> H003 : Note = Phone_invalid_format
> H004 : Note = Phone_invalid_format
> H005 : Note = Phone_invalid_format
> H006 : Note = Phone_invalid_format
> H010 : Note = Phone_invalid_format
```

so far all i can get is to detect how many array or object in the string, but failed in retrieve the value in it.

Comment: TlkJSON seems abandonned. You probably need to look at the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/) yourself to understand how it works.

Comment: @fpiette thank's for the advice, except that i,m not quite get the grasp for differentiate between how to handle data in Object that diverted from tlkjsonbase in the source code that provided.

Comment: It could be helpful @Panda_Sumatra if you posted a short example of some JSON you wish to parse. And information if the structure is always the same (known), or it is unknown structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in lkJSON to find the type of element. This is called `SelfType`, enumeration of `TlkJSONtypes: (jsBase, jsNumber, jsString, jsBoolean, jsNull, jsList, jsObject)`.

You can write this out using `SelfTypeName` where you get the same as enum, only as a string.

So basically something along:

```pascal
begin
  js := TlkJSON.ParseText(txt);
  writeln(js.SelfTypeName);    // get the type as a string
  if js.SelfType in [jsList] then
     begin
       // process as list
     end
  else
  if js.SelfType in [jsObject] then 
    begin
      // process as object
    end
  else if js.SelfType not in [jsBase] then 
    begin
     // write the value of number, string, boolean, null
    end;
end;
```

Obviously you can then make a `parse_element` function which you can call recursively.

lkJSON seems to be still updated, [this GitHub project](https://github.com/otomazeli/lkJSON) lists 1.09 from 1 Oct 2021.

The documentation is fairly sparse, but it does the job on older Delphi versions where [superobject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) unfortunately won't compile.

If you google keywords like `SelfName` and `lkJSON` there are plenty examples online to get you going.

Comment: why do you have to call writeln function first?

Comment: I don't of course, this is just example code to see example of usage. You can also compare directly instead of using `in [...]`.